# Creating 5 Open Spots in 3 Different Scenario's via CSS's Nth-Child

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have row's of divs that are floated left, in three different scenarios. With each scenario I'm trying to make all of my divs line up at the bottom, while using the same amount of divs for each scenario and making 5 criss crossed open spots. Sound confusing? Let me give you my scenarios..

**Scenario One**

43 divs. 4 divs per row with 5 open spots. Divs line up fine at the bottom (assuming each blank spot will be filled with a div).

http://jsfiddle.net/XXfe2/1/

**Scenario Two**

43 divs. 3 divs per row with 5 open spots. Divs line up fine at the bottom (assuming each blank spot will be filled with a div).

http://jsfiddle.net/XXfe2/9/

**Scenario Three (doesn't work)**

43 divs. 5 divs per row with 5 open spots. Divs don't line up at the bottom, there would be two open spots, assuming one last open spot at the bottom row will be filled with a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/XXfe2/8/

So, scenario three with 5 divs per row is the only one that doesn't work.  There would be two extra open spots.  I would like to find a way to make all divs line up at the bottom with 5 open spots, or if it's not possible to do this with 5, maybe 4 or 6.. I'm not too great at math.  And I DO NOT wan't to resort to setting divs to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` to hide an extra div or two.

So how would I make this work and have all the divs line up at the bottom for 5, 4, and 3 divs per row while having the same amount of divs and open spots for each scenario?  Any help would truely be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

After spending days of testing I found out that having **64 divs / boxes** for each scenario (5, 3, and 4 divs per row) with **6 open spots** in each scenario worked and perfectly lines up all the divs at the bottom.